# Getting "Operation does not exist" error when trying to create RMA shipping label for Fedex

Tags: shipping, fedex

Creating shipping labels through the `Enterprise_Rma` module using UPS is working fine.  I'm trying to add support for Fedex now.

When I try to create the shipping label, I get an error: *An error occurred while creating shipping label.*.

[image]

I dug in and inspected the underlying SoapClient object in `Mage_Usa_Model_Shipping_Carrier_Fedex::_doShipmentRequest()` and I'm seeing that the SOAP error is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header />
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en">Fault</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <cause>UnrecoverableInternalError</cause>
                <code>OperationNotSupported</code>
                <desc>Operation does not exist: {http://fedex.com/ws/ship/v10}ProcessShipmentRequest</desc>
            </detail>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

What's this all about?  Does something need to be configured in the Fedex account in order to open up access to this particular API method?

UPDATE: It looks like this is because we're not yet certified to print labels in production yet.  A better error message could have saved a lot of time in figuring that out.  Also the fedex tech support email list on their site (websupport@fedex.com) has never replied to any emails I've sent there.  And when you call in, they will tell you that they don't have any access to email.  Very strange.

Comment: kalen, please add the solution and information as an answer and mark it as solution!

Comment: The only thing is that I was planning to wait until I finalized the certification so that I know for sure that was the issue.  Especially since SO doesn't let you change an answer after you've accepted it...?

Comment: Oh, really? I didn't know this :-) Thanks for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the reason for the error was that we were not yet certified to print labels in production.

Comment: How to solve this issue?